# Windows 10 ISO on USB stick won't boot

Tags: linux, windows-10, usb, iso-image, bootable-media

I've been trying to install Windows 10 on a Thinkpad R60 for two weeks and went through several tutorials on how to create a bootable ISO on Linux/Debian 9. This one finally seemed to work (i.e. without running into any trouble in between):

https://wycd.net/posts/2015-03-10-creating-a-bootable-windows-10-usb-drive-on-linux.html

Unfortunately, the laptop won't boot the ISO. I already set the boot order in BIOS to check for external USB drives first. What am I missing?

Comment: With an R60, you unfortunately do not have UEFI. The guide looks good though. Can you describe ([in your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1360972/edit)) what happens after selecting your USB drive in the boot selection menu?

Comment: I had wiped the laptop HDD, so after power up I got to a blank screen with a blinking cursor. Problem solved, see below :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOLVED: Need to set the drive as **bootable**

Can be done using `Gnome-Disk` - in Debian:
Applications >> Accessories >> Disks >> Additional partition options >> Edit partition >> Bootable

Comment: I found an article about this issue. I paste the link here so that it might help more people.  https://www.iseepassword.com/windows-wont-boot-from-usb.html

Answer (score -1):

i stumbled upon this question but answer did not fit for me

so i googled more and posting here answer which worked:

https://www.onetransistor.eu/2014/09/make-bootable-windows-usb-from-ubuntu.html

there are four options covered in the link, i'll describe here one suitable

1. install GParted
2. select inserted flash drive
3. unmount
4. Device -> Create Partition Table -> msdos -> Apply
5. right click the unallocated space -> New
6. make a primary NTFS partition and give it a label
7. Apply all operations
8. right click the partition -> Manage flags
9. select boot
10. copy files from windows.iso
11. sync (takes a lot of time, if you want to see progress find how here on stackoverflow)
12. install grub-pc-bin
13. sudo grub-install --target=i386-pc --boot-directory="/media/<*username*>/<drive_label>/boot" /dev/sdX (also takes some time)
14. touch on usb /boot/grub/grub.cfg and copy there:

    ```
    default=1  
    timeout=15
    color_normal=light-cyan/dark-gray
    menu_color_normal=black/light-cyan
    menu_color_highlight=white/black

    menuentry "Start Windows Installation" {
        insmod ntfs
        insmod search_label
        search --no-floppy --set=root --label <USB_drive_label> --hint hd0,msdos1
        ntldr /bootmgr
        boot
    }

    menuentry "Boot from the first hard drive" {
        insmod ntfs
        insmod chain
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod part_gpt
        set root=(hd1)
        chainloader +1
        boot
    }
    ```

don't forget to replace anything <...> with your data

after that i got bootable flash with windows install